# This code is only displaying 0 output on the input of either 15 or any number why is that so? Is there something wrong with the code?

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract sec
{

    uint age= 15;
    uint agePer;

    modifier onlyPer (){

        if(age==agePer)
        {
            _;
        }
    }

    function getage(uint agep) onlyPer() public returns (uint){

        agePer=agep;
        return agePer;
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where exactly does this code "display" anything?

Answer (score 0):

`age` is 15, and `agePer` is 0, so `age == agePer` is not true. That means the body of `getage` never runs, and so the return value is always the default `uint` value of `0`.

Comment: i should pass a constructor to initalize agePer first then execute  getage function.

Comment: Also, the code is senseless. Set `agePer=agep` only if `agePer==agep`???

Comment: BTW, the modifier doesn't `require` nor `assert`, so I'm not sure that the body of the function never runs (I'm just not sure that it runs at all, because I can't see anyone calling this function to begin with).

Comment: @goodvibration The underscore in a modifier represents the function body. `if (false) { _; }` means the body of the function isn't executed.

Comment: Cool, was missing that part in my "vocabulary" (was always happy with the fact that this syntax worked, but never bothered to dive into it).